# Angular. CDK Overlay. Setup positionStrategy to flexible in template

Tags: angular, overlay, angular-cdk

How can I setup flexible position strategy via template? Is any convenient way to create position strategy instance?

```
        <button
            (mouseover)="isOpen = true" 
            (mouseout)="isOpen = false"
            cdkOverlayOrigin
            #trigger="cdkOverlayOrigin"
    >CLICK
    </button>

    <ng-template
            cdkConnectedOverlay
            [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="trigger"
            [cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="isOpen"
            [cdkConnectedOverlayScrollStrategy]="closeStrategy"
            [cdkConnectedOverlayPositionStrategy]=????
    ><div>CONTENT</div>
    </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable position and reference this in the HTML

```
yourComponent.ts
    .
    .
    .
public positions = [
   new ConnectionPositionPair({
       originX: 'end',
       originY: 'top'},{
       overlayX: 'end',
       overlayY: 'bottom'},
       0,
       50)
];

yourComponent.html
    .
    .
    .
[cdkConnectedOverlayPositionStrategy]="positions"
```